# Required Azure Permissions to edit Attributes and Claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, identity

I am working to identify what role I need to be inside of portal.azure.com to be able to create, edit, and delete claims and Enterprise Applications.   When logged in I can not change any claim value, name, or namespace.

[image: Azure Claims]

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I have been going back and forth for a month to figure out what permissions are needed and I have been assigned many of them with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD SAML Application and configured SSO** like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: To delete Attributes and Claims, the user must have either **Application Administrator or Global Administrator role**.

With the **required roles I am able to delete the Claims successfully** like below:

[image]

The Claim got deleted successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[App permissions for custom roles in Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-enterprise-app-permissions#manage-user-attributes-and-claims)